# Non existing content redirection

Tags: ee2, channel, 404

my google-fu failed again, and i have a serious problem. I have a channel and template for it called html, when i go to page.com/html/(existing article name), it works just fine, but when i go to page.com/html/(non-existing article), it shows the article with lowest ID instead. So what am i asking for? **How to redirect user to 404 page, when he opens page.com/html/(non-existing article name)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`require_entry` parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry):

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="1" require_entry="yes" [...]}
  {if no_results}
    {redirect="404"}
  {/if}
  [...]
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This parameter make the [`{if no_results}` conditional](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results) available.